# PayPal Adaptive Payments - Error 520009 - Account is restricted

Tags: api, paypal, payment, account

Apologies in advance if this is a silly question. I did try digging around, but couldn't find an answer.

I'm trying to set up a chained payment (at the sandbox environment), but am getting error 520009 (Account is restricted). Tried several email addresses, and they all give me this error. The email addresses are not registered with Paypal, but as far as I know this shouldn't be an issue as the adaptive payments module doesn't require the receivers to have Paypal accounts in advance (though they will need accounts to actually get the money, of course).

What am I doing wrong?
I did set the fee payer to EACHRECEIVER (as suggested on some threads), but the error remains.

This is what I get back: 
ERROR Code: 520009 
ERROR Message: Account someone1@gmail.com is restricted

Here's my code:

```
// Config
$endpoint = trim("https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay"); 
$API_UserName = "MY_USERNAME_FROM_SANDBOX";
$API_Password = "MY_PASSWORD_FROM_SANDBOX"; 
$API_Signature = "MY_SIGNATURE_FROM_SANDBOX";
$API_AppID = "APP-80W284485P519543T";    
$API_RequestFormat = "NV";
$API_ResponseFormat = "NV";

    // Create request payload with minimum required parameters
$bodyparams = array (   
        "requestEnvelope.errorLanguage" => "en_US",
        "actionType" => "PAY_PRIMARY",
        "cancelUrl" => 'http://www.beta.com/cancel',
        "returnUrl" => 'http://www.beta.com/return',
        "currencyCode" => 'USD',
        "feesPayer" => "EACHRECEIVER",
        "actionType" => "PAY_PRIMARY",
        "receiverList.receiver[0].email" => 'someone1@gmail.com',
        "receiverList.receiver[0].amount" => '10',
        "receiverList.receiver[0].primary" => 'true', 
        "receiverList.receiver[1].email" => 'someone2@gmail.com',
        "receiverList.receiver[1].amount" => '5',
        "receiverList.receiver[1].primary" => 'false', 
    );

    // Convert payload array into url encoded query string
    $body_data = http_build_query($bodyparams, "", chr(38));

try
{
     //create request and add headers
$params = array("http" => array(
    "method" => "POST",
    "content" => $body_data,
    "header" =>  
        "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID: " . $API_UserName . "\r\n" .
        "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE: " . $API_Signature . "\r\n" .
        "X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD: " . $API_Password . "\r\n" .
        "X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID: " . $API_AppID . "\r\n" .
        "X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT: " . $API_RequestFormat . "\r\n" .
        "X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT: " . $API_ResponseFormat . "\r\n" 
        ));

    //create stream context
     $ctx = stream_context_create($params);

    //open the stream and send request
 $fp = @fopen($endpoint, "r", false, $ctx);

    //get response
     $response = stream_get_contents($fp);

    //check to see if stream is open
 if ($response === false) {
    throw new Exception("php error message = " . "$php_errormsg");
     }

    //close the stream
     fclose($fp);

    //parse the ap key from the response 
$keyArray = explode("&", $response);

    foreach ($keyArray as $rVal){
        list($qKey, $qVal) = explode ("=", $rVal);
            $kArray[$qKey] = $qVal;
    }

    //print the response to screen for testing purposes
If ( $kArray["responseEnvelope.ack"] == "Success") {

         foreach ($kArray as $key =>$value){
        echo $key . ": " .$value . "<br/>";
}
 }
else {
    echo 'ERROR Code: ' .  $kArray["error(0).errorId"] . " <br/>";
  echo 'ERROR Message: ' .  urldecode($kArray["error(0).message"]) . " <br/>";
    }

   } 
catch(Exception $e) {
    echo "Message: ||" .$e->getMessage()."||";
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error #520009 - Account is restricted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247050/error-520009-account-is-restricted)

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT: I could solve the problem by removing the "feesPayer" param, which needs to be the default value (i.e., EACHRECEIVER) in case of a unilateral payment.**

I'm stuck with this issue, too.

I wonder how I could achieve a "unilateral payment", which is described by PayPal as follows:

> You can use the Pay API operation to make unilateral payments under
>   limited circumstances. A unilateral payment is a payment that is made
>   to a receiver who does not have a PayPal account. Unilateral payments
>   can be used with simple or parallel payments that are implicit or
>   preapproved. Unilateral payments are not designed to be used with
>   chained payments or payments that require manual approval through the
>   web flow. When you send a unilateral payment, you send a payment
>   request that includes an email address for a receiver, and this email
>   address is not linked to a registered PayPal account. The receiver
>   receives an email notifying the receiver to create an account and
>   claim the payment. PayPal holds a payment to a receiver whose email
>   address is not yet registered or confirmed until the receiver creates
>   a PayPal account and confirms the email address. If a refund specifies
>   a receiver whose email address is not yet registered or confirmed, the
>   payment to the receiver is canceled.

Anyone having an idea what parameter-setting using NVP is required to achieve this without getting `ERROR Code: 520009 ERROR Message: Account someone1@gmail.com is restricted`

Any hint is highly appreciated!

Comment: Thank you so much... I can hardly understand Paypal documentation.

Answer (score 0):

> "but as far as I know this shouldn't be an issue as the adaptive
>   payments module doesn't require the receivers to have Paypal accounts
>   in advance "

That's incorrect. For Adaptive Chained Payments, all receivers must have an active and verified Personal, Premier or Business PayPal account.

Comment: According to 'Adaptive Payments Developer Guide SOAP API Developer ReferencePP_AdaptivePayments.pdf'; "The application owner must have a PayPal Business account. Senders and receivers can have any PayPal account type"

Comment: The application owner and the receiver(s) can be different accounts, thus have different requirements. ;-)

Comment: Don't understand this comment. For chained payments receivers do NOT need Premier or Business PayPal accounts. They just need an active/verified PayPal account.

Comment: Oops, I forgot about 'Personal' accounts. Not all countries offer 'Personal' account types anymore (they automatically create 'Premier' accounts). Apologies for the confusion. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Is there a link in the documentation that states this limitation about chained payments? Thank you.